# How can i get rid of this c# error

Tags: c#

this is my error.

> There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

this is my code

```
string conn = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconn"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(conn);
            myConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Register(Email,Username,Password,Confirm_Password) values('" + txtEmail.Text + "','" + txtUsername.Text + "''" + Password.Text + "''" + ConfirmPassword.Text + "')", myConnection);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection.Close();
```

can somebody please help me?

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: As Grant Winney already indicated, there are missing some commas... Additionally your code is very prone to the threat of [SQL injection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx). So consider using [parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of string concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing 2 commas in that line.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Register(Email,Username,Password,Confirm_Password) values('" + txtEmail.Text + "','" + txtUsername.Text + "','" + Password.Text + "','" + ConfirmPassword.Text + "')", myConnection);
```

But as comments indicated you really should consider using parameterized queries. Also I can suggest EntitiyFramework too.